# Points buying without in-app purchase for purchasing rides

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, payment-gateway, payment

I am currently working in a ride providing app in which user can book a scheduled rides. The app will use a concept that the ride will show the cost of ride in some points system not in currency for uniformity across the countries. So user pays for points in respective countries and currency to they belong. 1 Point may have different value in different countries. User can buy points in advanced and can use later for buying a ride.

Below is the Apple guideline for in-app purchase

> Guideline 3.1.1 - In-App Purchase
>
> App contains a payment mechanism other than in-app purchase for
>   digital content or to unlock features or functionality within your
>   app, which is not appropriate for the App Store. In-app purchase is
>   the only valid in-app payment mechanism for digital content.
>
> Note: Continuing to hide functionality within your app or other
>   dishonest acts may result in the removal of your apps from the App
>   Store and termination of your Apple Developer Program membership and
>   all associated memberships.

My query is that if I use any payment method(credit/debit card, AliPay, PayTM) other than in-app purchase to purchase points, will that be allowed by Apple in the review.

Please share the experience if anyone went through this scenario. Thanks!

Comment: `In-app purchase is the only valid in-app payment mechanism for digital content.` Any in-app payment must be done through in-app purchase. Any other in-app payment method won't be allowed

Comment: you can use other payment gateways too, as you application is not only providing digital services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since rides are not digital content and you're providing a service outside the app I believe you are actually not allowed to use in-app purchases - probably a good thing for you :)

> 3.1.5 (a) Goods and Services Outside of the App: If your app enables people to purchase goods or services that will be consumed outside of
>   the app, you must use purchase methods other than in-app purchase to
>   collect those payments, such as Apple Pay or traditional credit card
>   entry.

As long as your "coins" can only be used for rides, and not unlock additional functionality within the app, you aren't breaking any guidelines.

There are probably some legal/liability reasons why Apple doesn't want to process payments for services outside the app, as well as being a poor customer experience to deal with refunds, etc.